# Debian : how to use a sudo bash script without password at startup

Tags: shell-script, debian, sudo, cron

I am on Debian 11 testing. It's a low-end computer intended for users with little computer experience and I want to keep it up to date with a script that do not prompt users for a password.

Following the advice of several topics (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215604/use-sudo-without-password-inside-a-script)):

So I wrote a simple script `/home/user/Documents/update.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt autoclean -y
sudo apt autoremove -y
```

I then make the script executable:

```
chmod a+x /home/user/Documents/update.sh
```

Then I gave the user `user` the rights with `visudo` so as not to ask for the password

```
user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/user/Documents/update.sh, /usr/bin/apt update, /usr/bin/apt upgrade, /usr/bin/apt autoclean, /usr/bin/apt autoremove
```

After testing by running the command on the terminal `sh '/home/user/Documents/update.sh'`, the script works without asking me for a password.

###### 1st try to run the script at startup with crontab :

To run the script at each startup, I modify `crontab -u user -e` (I also tested directly with `crontab -e`):

```
@reboot sh '/home/user/Documents/update.sh'
```

But on each reboot: no script starts.

###### 2nd try to run the script at startup with Gnome Tweaks and a desktop file :

As an alternative I try to make an `update.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` in which a double-click starts the script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=update
Exec=sh '/home/user/Documents/update.sh'
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
```

After testing, double-clicking on this file runs the script without asking for a password

Then, with *Gnome Tweaks*, I add the file `updates.desktop` as an application at startup

This is where my second problem comes in: the script starts at startup, but asks me for a password.

Then I don't understand why this happens (is Gnome Tweaks running under another user, etc.).

##### Questions :

1. Why the crontab method does not work ? (I already have started crontab service to be sure)
2. Why the Gnome Tweak method prompt me for a password and how to solve this issue ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: don't write commands you need to run as root in your user's crontab, but in the system-wide; that gets run by root, so you don't need sudo to start with. However, what you want to do is already solved by debian, [unattended upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades). And it's honestly a bit smarter than doing a full upgrade every boot – which is the worst time to do it, if your upgrade involves the kernel, kernel modules, or system libraries which will not be working until you reboot. So, wrong approach! If you want to enforce updates on every time you reboot, do the updating on

Comment: shutdown, not startup. Also, absolutely not clear what you need Gnome Tweaks (wow! That still exists!) for to start something: Your system has a service runtime manager, which is responsible for starting all other things on your system as well.

Comment: If a user can run `/usr/bin/apt update` with `sudo` without giving a password, then they must specify that command _exactly_ like that (`apt update -y` is not the same command so it wouldn't be allowed without a password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic thing you can do is prefix `/usr/bin` to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/bin/apt update -y
sudo /usr/bin/apt upgrade -y
sudo /usr/bin/apt autoclean -y
sudo /usr/bin/apt autoremove -y
```

This will work because you allowed the user to run `/usr/bin/apt` but not `apt`.  That's actually good because it stops someone from making their own malicious program called `apt` and putting it in a directory in `$PATH`.  However, I'd recommend against this because scripts depending on a NOPASSWD option are not the best.

---

The next easiest solution could be to replace `sudo` with `pkexec` to work with your script for use with the desktop entry.  `pkexec` is part of `polkit` and is the GUI-version of `sudo`.  It will dim your gnome session and prompt for a password instead of using a terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
pkexec /usr/bin/apt update -y
pkexec /usr/bin/apt upgrade -y
pkexec /usr/bin/apt autoclean -y
pkexec /usr/bin/apt autoremove -y
```

There are also ways to allow a user to do something without the interactive prompt.  You'll need to lookup polkit rules for that.  For example, this could work in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.update.policy`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>
  <vendor>Your name</vendor>
  <action id="org.update">
    <description>Update the system</description>
    <message>This will run apt update/upgrade and then autoremove.</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/apt</annotate>
  </action>
</policyconfig>
```

---

However, the best answer (especially if you prefer non-interactivity) is to run this as a service.  A simple solution might be:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/update.service
[Unit]
Description=Auto upgrade
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/apt update -y
ExecStart=/usr/bin/apt upgrade -y
ExecStart=/usr/bin/apt autoclean -y
ExecStart=/usr/bin/apt autoremove -y

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then use `sudo systemctl enable --now update.service` to run it and arm it for the next boots.

---

`apt` (at least in Debian's distribution) already has something similar to the service solution:  `apt-daily.service` and `apt-daily-upgrade.service` which are triggered once per day and do some updating for you.

Take a look at

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` and `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systed.daily` for instructions on how to configure it to do what you want.  I think this solution is even better than making your own services because edge cases and stability which could break your system have already been addressed by the authors of `apt` itself.  For example, if the autoclean would uninstall `libc6` or `linux-*` this script will avoid that.

Something like this might work (these values are all 0-disabled by default):

```
# /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic

# Run 'apt update' every day
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists 1

# Run 'apt-get autoclean' every 1 day
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval 1

# Run apt-get clean every 1 day
APT::Periodic::CleanInterval 1

# Run unattended-upgrade every 1 day 
# This is similar to `apt upgrade` depending on your configuration
# (requires package 'unattended-upgrade')
# This effectively does the 'apt upgrade'
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade 1

# Run `apt autoremove` after upgrading
# This may be set in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
#  You might want to set this in that other file to avoid
#  getting confused about what goes where
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependency "true"
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have tried your methods but only *unattended upgrades* worked following your advises. As a note, I add an answer explaining how I have set up my config.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, this is the way I have set up *unattended-upgrades*.

#### Debian packages

1. I have to install unattended-upgrades with

   ```bash
   sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
   ```
2. Then `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` to modify the config file with at least the following lines to uncomment :

   ```
   ...
   "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-updates";
   "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-proposed-updates";
   "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
   "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
   ...
   Unattended-Upgrade::AutoFixInterruptedDpkg "true";
   Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";
   ...
   Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";
   ...
   Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-New-Unused-Dependencies "true";
   Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
   ...
   Unattended-Upgrade::OnlyOnACPower "false";
   ```
3. Then to launch updates at startup (because the computer is not used many time, so it could need security patches), I need a new service:

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service
   ```

   containing:

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=Unattended Upgrades
   After=apt-daily.service apt-daily-upgrade.service apt-daily-upgrade.timer apt-get-upgrade.service

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
4. Now, enable the service:

   ```bash
   systemctl enable unattended-upgrades.service
   ```
5. Then to get this every day, we have to run `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` and modifying it with the following content :

```
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "1";
APT::Periodic::CleanInterval 1;
```

7. Finally to get this at startup (as I would like), you have first to run `sudo systemctl edit apt-daily.timer` (timing the apt update service) with the following content :

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt download activities

[Timer]
OnStartupSec=20
RandomizedDelaySec=5
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

and running also `sudo systemctl edit apt-daily-upgrade.timer` with the following content :

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
After=apt-daily.timer

[Timer]
OnStartupSec=60
RandomizedDelaySec=10
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

#### Flatpak

1. Same for flatpak, we have first to run `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/flatpak-update.service` with the following content :

```
[Unit]
Description=Update Flatpak
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/flatpak update --noninteractive --assumeyes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. And we have also to run `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/flatpak-update.timer` with the following content :

```
[Unit]
Description=Update Flatpak

[Timer]
OnBootSec=2m
OnActiveSec=2m
OnUnitInactiveSec=24h
OnUnitActiveSec=24h
AccuracySec=1h
RandomizedDelaySec=10m

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

3. Finally, we have to run successively :

```
systemctl enable flatpak-update.service
```

```
systemctl enable flatpak-update.timer
```

```
systemctl start flatpak-update.service
```

```
systemctl start flatpak-update.timer
```

Thanks to Stewart, all member who helped me, and ChatGPT !